# Why use 0.5 as the parameter of Poisson distribution in ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

according the java doc in ConcurrentHashMap:

```
 * Ideally, the frequency of nodes in bins follows a Poisson distribution
 * (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) with a
 * parameter of about 0.5 on average, given the resizing threshold
 * of 0.75, although with a large variance because of resizing
 * granularity. Ignoring variance, the expected occurrences of
 * list size k are (exp(-0.5) * pow(0.5, k) / factorial(k)). The
 * first values are:
```

Question is: How does the 0.5 parameter come?

Comment: I don't have a source for this, but I do recall reading somewhere that it's basically a guesstimate from empirically observed runs. I'm guessing they had a bunch of example use cases of CHM that they felt were a good representation of "typical" use, played around with some numbers, and found that 0.5 seems to work well.

Comment: @yshavit I think I got the reason: see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the reason for 0.5:
the max elements counts is `0.75 * bin[].length`, then the bin will be resized.
So assume the elements counts is: `0.5 * bin[].length`, then the average element counts per bin is 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

it's because the average of 0.75 and 0.375(the loading rate after rehash) is 0.5625 which is approximately 0.5 it's not guesstimate

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).